# Python - Log the changes needed for one list of dictionaries to be updated to another

Tags: python, list, dictionary, comparison, difference

I have two large lists of dictionaries:

```
list1 = [{name: "John", age: 25}, {name: "Sarah", age: 31}, {name: "Frank", age: 12}]
list2 = [{name: "John", age: 25}, {name: "Sarah", age: 32}, {name: "Dave", age: 13}]
```

The idea is to log the changes needed in order to update `list1` to `list2`.

```
add = []          
remove = []      
age_diff = []
```

`add` holds the names of anyone unique in `list2` that should be added to `list1`

`remove` holds the names of anyone unique to `list1` that should be removed

`age_diff` holds the names of anyone whose age changed between `list1` and `list2`

This is how I've been doing it:

```
for item1 in list1:
    if any(item2["name"] == item1["name"] for item2 in list2):
        # if item1["age"] != item2["age"]:                         # won't work as item2
            # age_diff.append(item1["name"])                       # can't be accessed. 
    else:
        add.append(item1["name"])

for item2 in list2:
    if any(item1["name"] == item2["name"] for item1 in list1):
        pass
    else:
        remove.append(item2["name"])
```

A nested `for i in range()` loop would allow me to do the comparison for `age`, but it doesn't feel very pythonic. I was hoping to use `set()` comparison for the lists instead of appending the results to a new list, but I don't think there's a way to do this for my purposes.

***Edited to include example***

Comment: can you give us sample `list1` and `list2` and expected output?

Comment: @BAH Sure! Done.. Apologies for that. Kinda new to stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first loop don't just test the condition with any, set the equivalent item2 to a variable so you can use it to compare the age inside the if statement. So I would change:

```
if any(item2["name"] == item1["name"] for item2 in list2):
```

to:

```
item2 = [x for x in list2 if x["name"] == item1["name"]]
```

item2 now holds a list of matches by name. Assuming that's always going to be 0 or 1 items, you can continue with testing item2[0] (as in your comment) like this:

```
if item2:
    if item1["age"] != item2[0]["age"]:
        age_diff.append(item1["name"])
else:
    add.append(item1["name"])
```